# How to express the workflows and data structures of a shopping site in a database schema and operations on it?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, e-commerce, netbeans-8

I'm working on a very ambitious e-commerce project. So far I have all my html templates created with Notepad++. I like to work in NetBeans using the MVC Cake Framework concept, which in my opinion is very easy to understand.

I know how to create a simple shopping cart with basic commands like add and delete. I also know how to work with MySQL databases (which I assume is all it takes). I'd like to push the game further by developing a full blown complex application like Walmart or Amazon where the customer can:

- Log in
- Manage their account
- Manage a wishlist
- View Order History
- Manage Gift Cards & Vouchers
- View, print invoices
- Earn points in a customer reward system by reviewing products, sharing on social medias, passing orders
  ... and so on.

1- Has anyone of you done it? Is it possible using MVC Cake Framework?

2- As for the registration process and everything, I know it's mostly just database stuff, but how do I develop a Wishlist... The kind of wishlist that can be created by visitors without them having to register to add items on it BUT if they want to manage and save it, they need to create an account...

3- What about the "Air miles *kind of* reward system that is associated with one's account and activities (sharing on social medias, purchasing on the site, reviewing products...etc)? Is it just database stuff also? Doable with MySQL and MVC?

I hope I'm being clear enough to understand! Any form of help, feedback or input would be gladly appreciated! I'd love to hear about your experiences!

Comment: 1. Yes. Such projects are quite ambitious on your own. Personally, I have never used the MVC Cake Framework, but I see no problems with using it. 2. Have you tried anything so far? I think you already have a concept for your implementation of your wishlist.

Comment: 1a) yes 1b) yes 2) use cookies to store none-logged in once registered/logged in then save cookie data to DB etc

Comment: @Arturil. It is very ambitious I know! But I have lots of time on my hand these days and I thought about having fun with the codes you know! So far I have created blogs and simple shopping carts. Regular stuff. What about you? Which frameworks do you use?

Comment: @Dave. Do you have a site I can check for educational purpose? Which framework did you use, if you used one? Did you even work with PHP? How did you go about the wishlist? How many days/weeks or months did it take you? If you don't mind sharing your knowledge of course! ^^

Comment: Yes, every point of it can easily be done. Alltogether it will indeed be still quite ambiguous. I recommend using CakePHP3.0 (RC still, but soon stable) if you chose Cake.

Comment: It did one over a weekend about 7 years ago it was actually a "re-write" of a very bad attempt at an e-commerce site by an indian code shop.  It does however have everything as a feature you listed, it doesn't use a framework and the php code is very very very bad but you could perhaps use it as a basis http://sourceforge.net/projects/ez-shop total time to write that was about 40 hours, but difference was I was already an experienced developer + I took a lot of bad practice short cuts to get it done so fast.

Comment: @mark. Yes Cake is the easiest to install in my opinion... Zend is quite a monster and gave me headaches... When you say easily done, you mean within days, weeks or months? Have you done it yourself? ^^

Comment: @Dave. Thanks for the input mate! I'm checking everything live! I will get back to you! Cheers!

Comment: @user23524697 Currently I am using Laravel as a framework. Recently I have programmed on several applications, mostly a PoS system and an integration between that system and an existing web shop. Unfortunately, this code is closed source :S.

Comment: @Dave I would never ever recommend anyone to take a look a terrible code made in India. Except you want to show somebody how to **not** do something. Especially since you already say its very very bad, why do you recommend to take a look at it at all?

Comment: @burzum so he can get an idea of the work flows and how to implement the features.  I rewrote about 90% of the code but its bad still inline html all procedural etc its also very very old code but the idea isn't so much to copy the code as to see how it works so he can get his head around how he needs to implement things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- Has anyone of you done it? Is it possible using MVC Cake Framework?

Yes https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-cart-plugin

But this is "just" a cart. If you look at it's features and architectures you see that this isn't the most trivial task. There are several things to take in consideration. I've worked on different ecommerce related projects before.

> 2- As for the registration process and everything, I know it's mostly
>   just database stuff, but how do I develop a Wishlist... The kind of
>   wishlist that can be created by visitors without them having to
>   register to add items on it BUT if they want to manage and save it,
>   they need to create an account...

Honestly, if you don't know how to develop a *trivial* wishlist I have serious doubts you'll be able to properly develop a complete ecommerce solution. A wishlist is basically just a jointable between products and users:

```
| id | user_id | product_id |
```

In CakePHP 2.x this is expressed as hasAndBelongsToMany association and in Cake3 it's called belongsToMany, it was just shortened.

> 3- What about the "Air miles kind of reward system that is associated
>   with one's account and activities (sharing on social medias,
>   purchasing on the site, reviewing products...etc)? Is it just database
>   stuff also? Doable with MySQL and MVC?

Again, that you ask that makes me think you lack the required experience. Sure this is in theory doable with any language and any database system, it doesn't even has to be MVC, there are multiple ways to Rome.

However, CakePHP + Mysql are a good choice. I would go for Cake 3.0 these days. I don't know what kind of answer you expect on this very broad question. The reward system and the social sharing are two different sub-systems that can work together. If you expect a full DB schema and architecture suggestions on this, sorry, it is simply too broad to be answered quickly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply burzum. I appreciate it. Yes I'm a rookie and I didn't lie about that! But I learn very fast (I've learned how to use Cake in few hours or so). I don't expect a full DB schema as like you mentioned my question is very broad. I just want to know about others experiences and what not how they would accomplish such an ambitious project. So far I'm enjoying every input! It's already helping me getting my head around things! I think too much most of the times and that's how things get complexed! I thought wishlists were more complicated then what you've said! Thanks a lot!